# How do I make Windows 11 automatically switch to headphone audio when I plug them in?

Tags: audio, windows-11, dell-inspiron, speakers, headphones

This used to work fine not sure what happened. I used to be able to unplug/plug in my headphones and the audio and volume would change accordingly. It was like it knew the headphones were in and loaded up another audio profile with headphones as the output and a different volume level. I've tried updating drivers and running the audio playback troubleshooter. Nothing. Any help appreciated.

Comment: This isn't Windows' fault.  This is usually a feature of the audio driver (I am guessing that you are using RealTek).  I am speaking from win10 experience but I am very sure that this hasn't changed.  Disabling stuff in startup can cause this to no longer function.  In the case I am thinking about is Waves MaxxAudio Service (which isn't actuallly a service) or disabling services that got installed with the initial driver.  I fought uninstalling/reinstalling different versions for a while before I got it to work again.

Comment: Please give more information about computer model, headset model, installed driver and the plug-in port.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that the driver based approach is far from perfect. The closest alternatives are:

- **Software switch with a key binding**

This solution is not automatic, but you can use software audio switchers (AudioSwitch, AudioSwitcher, NirSoft etc.), which are based on key bindings.

- **Audio switchers**

There are also hardware switchers called audio switchers too (what a surprise!), however you will need to connect speakers and headphones to same, physical box - still manual toggle. The closest you can get to automatic switching is audio switch headphone stand, but it is still not on the market - worth to be followed.